# redirect user if not logged in

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am using customized pages on my site where I need to check that the user is logged in, and if not, redirect to another page.
On successful login, a session variable is set up as:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
```

To check whether the user is logged in or not on a page, I use this code at the start of the page:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']=='')
{
    @header("location:login.php");
}
```

However the page does not redirect even if the user is not logged in. The error shown is

> Notice: Undefined index: login in XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX

Is there any other method to redirect users other than `header()`, or maybe some other code can be used to achieve the same purpose?

Comment: Did you create a login.php as template or only a custom file? OR you can try with is_user_logged_in().

Comment: Use is_user_logged_in() function to check whether the user is login or not. then use  wp_redirect function to redirect to desire location

Comment: I am using login.php as a custom file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `login` index of `$_SESSION` is not set at the time you're checking it, most probably the `$_SESSION['login'] = "1";` bit comes after your check, so you are going to have to make sure you verify whether it's set or not using the `array_key_exists` function as follows:

```
if (array_key_exists('login', $_SESSION) && $_SESSION['login']=='') {
    @header("location:login.php");
}
```

Alternatively you may want to set explicitly `$_SESSION['login'] = 0`, for example, by default, and only set `$_SESSION['login'] = "1";` if login is successful.

At the same time, I do not recommend you to use your own login mechanism, instead use scripts and techniques originally designed by knowledgeable coders of wordpress, and well tested by the community. One such approach is described in [this question on the wordpress support site](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-different-front-page-if-not-logged-in?replies=3#post-2313926) (add this to your theme's `functions.php`):

```
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_visitors' );

function redirect_visitors() {
  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://your-site.com/wp-login.php' );
    exit;
  }
}
```